# Negative time difference in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timestamp, timedelta

I get this strange result by substracting earlier time stamp for later one:

```
pd.to_datetime('2021-05-21 06:00:00') - pd.to_datetime('2021-05-21 06:02:00')
```

Output:

```
Timedelta('-1 days +23:58:00')
```

Expected Output:

```
Timedelta('-0 days 00:02:00')
```

What is the correct way to calculate a negative time difference? Thank you!

Comment: please update your question with pandas version

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: @Umar.H I mean I expect - 2 Minutes, not - 2 days.

Comment: Well this is giving correct  output ... Your result is `Timedelta('-1 days +23:58:00')` which is equal to `-24:00:00 + 23:58:00` => `2 mins`

Comment: @MykolaZotko.. I just did that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Timedelta('-1 days +23:58:00')` *is* the proper representation of a negative time difference in pandas (and also in pure python)

```
# using pure python
from datetime import datetime
datetime(2021,5,21,6,0,0) - datetime(2021,5,21,6,2,0)
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86280)
```

this is because the difference is properly calculated as `-120 seconds`, but individual time elements cannot exceed their *moduli*. the timedelta components are normalized. To represent negative 2 minutes, a negative day & positive time component are used.

[from the python datetime module's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects)

> and days, seconds and microseconds are then normalized so that the representation is unique, with

> - 0 <= microseconds < 1000000
> - 0 <= seconds < 3600*24 (the number of seconds in one day)
> - -999999999 <= days <= 999999999

> Note that normalization of negative values may be surprising at first. For example:

```
from datetime import timedelta
d = timedelta(microseconds=-1)
(d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
(-1, 86399, 999999)
```

it is possible to retrieve the total seconds as a negative integer using the method `Timedelta.total_seconds`

Answer (score 5):

We can do `total_seconds`

```
(pd.to_datetime('2021-05-21 06:00:00') - pd.to_datetime('2021-05-21 06:02:00')).total_seconds()
Out[9]: -120.0
```

Comment: Could you please explain the default behavior.

Comment: I can imagine something like this happening: the timedelta object calculates a complete day back and then adds the number of  hours:min:sec to that value. Which, technically is correct, but hard to look at. Just an observation.

Answer (score 3):

Use `abs` to get the time delta:

```py
>>> abs(pd.to_datetime('2021-05-21 06:00:00') - pd.to_datetime('2021-05-21 06:02:00'))
Timedelta('0 days 00:02:00')
```

Comment: note that this is the incorrect delta, OP was curious how one might represent the delta as `0 days -00:02:00'`

Comment: In this case you are loosing important information about negative time. If you compare for example which process last longer, you want to know that suddenly the time is lower than 0

Answer (score 2):

Well your code is giving correct output ...
Your result is `Timedelta('-1 days +23:58:00')`  which is equal to `-24:00:00 + 23:58:00` => `2 mins`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `np.timedelta64` to change the time delta to your desired output

as others have said, the pandas negative `Timedelta` object is the correct output in python.

```
import numpy as np
delta = pd.to_datetime('2021-05-21 06:00:00') - pd.to_datetime('2021-05-21 06:02:00')


print(delta)
Timedelta('-1 days +23:58:00')

#minutes
print(delta / np.timedelta64(1,'m')
-2.0
#seconds
delta / np.timedelta64(1,'s')
-120.0
```