# Why is the difference between datetimes not symmetric?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

When I subtract start time from end time, I get `10 days, 7:39:11` as the answer whereas when end time is subtracted from start time, the answer is `-11 days, 16:20:49`. Why is this so? The result should be the same with a negative sign, no?

```
import datetime

datetime_start = datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 13, 3, 31, 47, 466744)
datetime_end = datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 23, 11, 10, 58, 466744)

date_diff = datetime_end - datetime_start
print(type(date_diff))
print(date_diff)

date_diff = datetime_start - datetime_end
print(type(date_diff))
print(date_diff)
```

Comment: Maybe this answer helps? [Negative time difference in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67637790/15740324)

Comment: The point being, it goes back to -11 days and then adds the hours. So the behavior is correct, just our interpretation being different.

Comment: see also [Python timedelta object with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46803405/10197418)